# How to parse word files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, docx

I want to be able to parse Word files in my project.
For example, I need to find a title or a table there. Or define the font name and font size. How do i do this? Are there any gems for this?

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum to ask for 3rd party library recommendations. (Honestly, a quick google search would have found you the same answer.) However, if you've tried using some library, got stuck and can **show us some code**, then StackOverflow is a good place to ask for pointers on what you might need to try next.

Comment: @TomLord Just out of curiosity. What is a good website where you can get opinion based answers? Such as recommendations about gems, pattern implementations, software, etc.

Comment: A discussion forum - e.g. discourse, or reddit, or hacker news,... Or you could use a  discussion group on slack, or the ruby talk group (email list), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [docx](https://github.com/chrahunt/docx) gem for that.

Comment: But what if I need to do the same for pdf or Linux .odt file? There is no universal tool for this?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to build a "universal tool" like that. It would be code bloat. Someone else, who only wants to deal with `.docx` files, would complain that the library is unnecessarily large - as it supports all sorts of other use cases.

Comment: If you need to process `.pdf` files (which you never mentioned in the original question, I might add), use a second library.

Comment: ODT, DOCX and PDF are completely different formats, no wonder they have separate libs for processing.

Comment: Got it. Thank you